# How do I send large data files using HttpClient.PostAsync?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, httpclient

My function is below. It works just great with anything up to around 25MB, but greater than that and it stops working. When I say stops working, it throws no exceptions and fails to the `noserver` result option at the bottom of the function. I can't seem to find any settings referring to any other buffer size though I found some Microsoft Documentation which does say the response buffer is 2GB default.

Any ideas, any help would be appreciated.

- VS2019 ASP.NET
- 4.7.2
- Winforms

  ```
  public async Task<JsonApiResult> GetHttpData(string Message, string serviceMethod)
  {
      System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print($"{serviceMethod}{Message}");

      HttpClient _httpClient = new HttpClient();

      _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
      _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
      _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/text"));

      _httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri(_url);

      try
      {
          //////
          StringContent payload = new StringContent(Message, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

          HttpResponseMessage getResponse = await _httpClient.PostAsync(serviceMethod, payload);

          if (getResponse.IsSuccessStatusCode)
          {
              try
              {
                  var response = getResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

                  JsonApiResult result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsonApiResult>(response);

                  return result;
              }
              catch (Exception e)
              {
                  return new JsonApiResult { Result = "fail", Message = e.Message, Data = "" };
              }
          }
          else
          {
              //<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
              return new JsonApiResult { Result = "fail", Message = getResponse.StatusCode.ToString(), Data = "" };
          }
      }
      catch (Exception e)
      {
          return new JsonApiResult { Result = "errserver", Message = e.Message, Data = "" };
      }

      return new JsonApiResult { Result = "noserver", Message = "Could not connect to server", Data = "" };
  }
  ```

On the server-side I'm using

```
    public async Task<JsonApiResult> GetMyFileUploads([FromBody]JsonApiResult result)
    {
    ...
```

Comment: I find it weird that it's not throwing any exceptions, it shouldn't be able to,mind going through that function while dedugging on a step-by-step approach ? To see which line fails ?

Comment: If you can avoid it don't send large data encapsulated as JSON, send it als plain raw data instead (working with large JSON data always requires a lot of RAM). Second use `GetStreamAsync` to avoid first reading the complete response into memory. Using the stream you can e.g. directly save the incoming data to a file.

Comment: @Sidewinder94 I have tried to step through it and the last thing it does is the line under `////` it pauses for a while then drops straight the `noserver` result line. None of the exceptions gets triggered. I'm using JSON as I send multiple items of related data at the same time. so I know how to process it on the server. @Robert note I am sending the data to a server. I only want the small response back

Comment: OK,k I did a little more digging and found this on the line under `//<<<<`. I get an error  `StatusCode: 404, ReasonPhrase: 'Not Found', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent` . It kinda looks like a buffer overrun. Like I said 25MB or more this happens, anything less is fine